# Continuity of a function defined as maximum of n continuous functions.

Tags: continuity

Let f1, . . . , fn be real valued functions defined on a set S in R. Assume that each fi is continuous at a ∈ S. For each x ∈ S, define f(x) to be the largest of the numbers f1(x), . . . , fn(x). Is f continuous at a?

Comment: Since $\max(f,g)=\frac{1}{2}\left[(f+g)+|f-g|\right]$. The right side is a sum of continuous functions, so max function is continuous.

Comment: Extension to any natural number n?

Comment: Hint: $\max(f,g,h)=\max(f,\max(g,h))$.